# iPhone icons, Retina only?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, icons, retina-display

I'm building an app which relies on the gyroscope which is only available on iPhone 4+.  Thus I really only need consider Retina displays in my design.

Is there a way to specify only hi-res images in Interface Builder.  Is there a Retina preview mode for IB (like there is for Simulator)?

I know about points versus pixels but currently, it seems I need to make both `myicon.png` and `myicon@2x.png` versions and specify the *former* in IB.  If I only make only the former OR the later, even if they are hi-res, when they reach my iphone they've been scaled up to the size they would appear on a non-Retina display (and pixelated as a result).

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, the answer is "NO".  Include 2 images, with both naming schemes.

You can, however, choose to have them both be the same retina resolution. I'd imagine though it's just plain safer to rescale them in bulk prior to deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You still need the non-retina versions for iPad

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise that the iPad has an gyro until now.  I'm not sure though that my app will be suitable for the iPad regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider that there may be future versions of iOS devices that have different combination of features.  It's best to check for each feature that you need individually.

Comment: Yes, I agree this is a good policy in general.  With regards to this issue though, I was of the mindset that one should avoid doing work to cover bases that don't currently exist and which may need changing once they do.  My current thinking however, is that it's just easiest to downsize the images and make the 1x copy, or if iPad is not required, just use two copies which are both hi-res...